# Display each item in array on new line

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that looks like this:

```
let array = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
```

I need all to display all of these items on a new line so I use join

```
let joinedArray = array.join("\n")
```

If I log this it is looking correct, however I need to render it to the DOM and that's where the issue lies. How can I render each of these items seperated with a new line to the DOM?

```
return <MyComponent
      { array.length !== 0 &&
        <div>
            {joinedArray}
        </div>
      }
</MyComponent>;
```

Comment: Have you tried by joining using `<br>`?

Comment: @MohammadUsman Yes, unfortunately it is being ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply adding a new class say `addlinebreak` with `white-space: pre-line` style:

```js
let array = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
let joinedArray = array.join("\n")

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="addlinebreak">{joinedArray}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
.addlinebreak {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead you can add the text into a `<p>` tag with [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to render the needed **JSX**.

Try the following with `<p>` tag:

```
return <>
   { array && array.map(e => <p>{e}</p> }
</>
```

I hope this helps!